# How do i pattern match and keep writing to new file until another pattern match

Tags: perl

My goal is to find and print all the lines in a "big.v" file starting from pattern match "module" until "endmodule" into individual files.

```
big.v: module test;
       <bunch of code> 
       endmodule 
       module foo;
      <bunch of code>
      endmodule
```

And the individual files would look like:

```
test.v : module test;
        ..
         endmodule

foo.v: module test1;
        ..
         endmodule
```

I got most of it working using:

```
use strict;
use warnings;

#open(my $fh, ">", $f1) || die "Couldn't open '".$f."' for writing because: ".$!;

while (<>) {
    my $line = $_; 
    if ($line =~ /(module)(\s+)(\w+)(.*)/) {
        my $modname = $3;
        open(my $fh1, ">", $modname.".v") ;
        print $fh1 $line."\n";
    ## how do i keep writing next lines to this file until following pattern
        if ($line =~ /(endmodule)(\s+)(.*)/) {  close $fh1;}
    }
}
```

Thanks,

Answer (score 7):

There's a useful perl construct called the 'range operator':
http://perldoc.perl.org/perlop.html#Range-Operators

It works like this:

```
while ( <$file> ) {
    if ( m/startpattern/ .. m/endpattern/ ) {
          print; 
    }
}
```

So given your example - I think this should do the trick:

```
my $output; 
while ( my $line = <STDIN> ) {
    if ( $line =~ m/module/ .. m/endmodule/ ) {
        my ( $modname ) = ( $line =~ m/module\s+(\w+)/ );
        if ( defined $modname) {
            open ( $output, ">", "$modname.v" ) or warn $!;
        } 
        print {$output} $line; 
    }
}
```

Edit:  But given your source data - you don't actually need to use a range operator I don't think. You could just close/reopen new 'output' files as you go. This assumes that you could 'cut up' your file based on 'module' lines, which isn't necessarily a valid assumption.

But sort of more like this:

```
use strict;
use warnings;

open ( my $input, "<", "big.v" ) or die $!;

my $output;
while ( my $line = <$input> ) {
    if ( $line =~ m/^\s*module/ ) {
        #start of module line found

        #close filehandle if it's open
        close($output) if defined $output;

        #extract the module name from the line. 
        my ($modulename) = ( $line =~ m/module\s+(\w+)/ );

        #open new output file (overwriting)
        open( $output, ">", "$modulename.v" ) or warn $!;
    }
    #this test might not be necessary. 
    if ( defined $output ) {
        print {$output} $line;
    }
}
```

Comment: Although, looking at the source data - I don't think you actually need the range operator, as you can just 'reopen' output each time you hit a 'module' line.

Comment: Since i am 'newbie' at perl though.. is there a way to make my code work? Just asking from learning perspective..thanks again.

Comment: Updated with another suggestion.

Comment: I do need the checks..because the "big.v" contains a whole lot more lines than just module/endmodule..thx.